# Property not recognized with WPF Styles and Derived Classes

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, styles

I'm having a problem with creating my styles for a custom wpf class.

This is what I have...

I have a class called FalconToggleButton that inherits System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton

FalconToggleButton has a new custom property called:

```
Public Property ButtonHoverIcon As System.Uri
```

FalconToggleButton also has other similar new methods and properties.

When I use the class I have no problems with it, when other classes inherit it they can use ButtonHoverIcon when they are defined through xaml or through code.

The problem happens when I try to make a style for FalconToggleButton

```
<Style x:Key="ToolBarMenuItemStyleDefault" TargetType="{x:Type DrawControl:FalconToggleButton}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property= "ButtonOffIcon" Value="pack://application:,,,/Images/WaitIcon.png"/>
</Style>
```

Property= "ButtonOffIcon" is not recognized as a valid property

When I run the code I  get a generic 
"XamlParseException occurred" message:
'Set property 'System.Windows.Setter.Property' threw an exception.' Line number '12' and line position '10'.

Do I need to register something somewhere to get my properties to show up in the styles structures?

Any help would be appreciated,
MS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to register your property as [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. For some reason it still does not set a value, but it is at least visible now.